# Spring Webflux Resource server and Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I have two separate micro-services: Authentication server and service with resources.
What I need is to obtain token from Authentication server and use this token to make request to resources service (and validate it and exchange it for username). At this moment I got following implementation which doesn't work properly.

application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom:
            client-id: SampleClientId
            client-secret: secret
            scopes: USER
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: http://localhost:8082/ui/login
        provider:
          custom:
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/authorize
            token-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/oauth/token
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:8081/auth/authenticate
```

Where http://localhost:8081/auth/authenticate returns Principal object in Authorization server.

SecurityConfig.class

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/health").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login()
                .and().build();
    }

}
```

And simple endpoint to retrive username in Resources server

```
@GetMapping("/username")
public Mono<String> getHesalth(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("custom") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient){
    return Mono.just(authorizedClient.getPrincipalName());
}
```

When I made request with token header:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:8605/username \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer {token-from-auth-server}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Resource server returns nothing and logs:

```
2019-10-20 21:44:38.641 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [edd1881d] HTTP GET "/username"
2019-10-20 21:44:38.704 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
2019-10-20 21:44:38.705 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : Processing */*
2019-10-20 21:44:38.705 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : Ignoring
2019-10-20 21:44:38.705 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] .s.u.m.MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher : Did not match any media types
2019-10-20 21:44:38.705 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [edd1881d] Completed 302 FOUND
2019-10-20 21:44:38.711 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Last HTTP response frame
2019-10-20 21:44:38.711 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] No sendHeaders() called before complete, sending zero-length header
2019-10-20 21:44:38.714 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
2019-10-20 21:44:38.715 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel
2019-10-20 21:44:38.715 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] No ChannelOperation attached. Dropping: EmptyLastHttpContent
2019-10-20 21:44:38.717 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Increasing pending responses, now 1
2019-10-20 21:44:38.717 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@3ec155e2
2019-10-20 21:44:38.717 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [edd1881d] HTTP GET "/oauth2/authorization/custom"
2019-10-20 21:44:38.732 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [edd1881d] Completed 302 FOUND
2019-10-20 21:44:38.734 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Last HTTP response frame
2019-10-20 21:44:38.735 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] No sendHeaders() called before complete, sending zero-length header
2019-10-20 21:44:38.735 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
2019-10-20 21:44:38.735 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel
2019-10-20 21:44:38.735 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-3] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xedd1881d, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33452] No ChannelOperation attached. Dropping: EmptyLastHttpContent
2019-10-20 21:44:38.738 DEBUG 29768 --- [or-http-epoll-4] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x93302880, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:8605 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:33454] New http connection, requesting read
```

It looks like resource server doesn't see token and redirect.
Does someone has a correct configuration for this case? Or where I made mistake?